# how can i do to give background color to the headers using alasql?

Tags: header, alasql, uibackgroundcolor

what is the right key word to give the header a bgcolor ?
`window.exportExcel =     function exportExcel(listPersone) {
                var fileName=prompt();
                var opts = {
                  headers:true, 
                  style:'background:#00FF00', //doesn't work
                  column: {style:{Font:{Bold:"1"}}},
                  rows: {1:{style:{Font:{Color:"#FF0077"}}}},
                  cells: {1:{1:{
                    style: {Font:{Color:"#00FFFF"}}
                  }}}
                };
                alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("'+fileName+'.xls",?) FROM ?',[opts,listPersone ]);
}`

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TByCm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution to give the header a background color !

```
var opts = {
              headers:true, 
              column: {
                  style:{
                      Font:{
                          Bold:"1",
                          Color:"#3C3741",
                      },
                      Alignment:{
                          Horizontal:"Center"
                      },
                      Interior:{
                          Color:"#7CEECE",
                          Pattern:"Solid"
                      }
                  },
              },
```